# select without replacement based on criteria

Tags: excel, replace, selection

select a cell based on criteria, see if that cell has been selected previously, if it has been selected previously, then ignore that cell and find the next nearest value, etc until all are exhausted.

more specifically, i am using and index and match function in cell AA02 to look at a group of values in z2:z101 and finding the closest value in a group of values from z102:201 and return that value into AA02.

however, i want the formula to look if the values from z102:201 has already been chosen, if so, ignore it and select the next closest value, assess if it was be chosen, if so move to the next closest value, and repeat.

i starting the formula in cell AA02 and copying it down through cell AA101.

thanks

Comment: So what is the problem you are running into with your approach?  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi ron,                                                                                                                            i cannot come up with an approach that evaluates whether or not the value i am searching for has already been previously chosen and then looks for the next closest number value.  i can develop a formula to determine the nearest value in a range, but am stuck after that.  thanks